# An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Tags: c#, mysql

```
                           //codigo de pesquisa
        string strconexao = "persist security info =false ; server=localhost ; database= iconefileequipamentos; uid=root";
        MySqlConnection oConn =new MySqlConnection(strconexao);
        StringBuilder strSQL =new StringBuilder();
        DataTable oTable =new DataTable();
        MySqlCommand oCmd =new MySqlCommand();

        oConn.Open();

        if (comboBox1.Text =="NomeResponsavel")
        {
            string NomeResponsavel = textBox1.Text; 
            strSQL.Append("Select *");
            strSQL.Append("FROM responsavelpc");
            strSQL.Append("Where Nomeresponsavel like '" + NomeResponsavel + "'");
        }

        if (comboBox1.Text == "NomeEquipamento")
        {
            string NomeEquipamento = textBox1.Text;
            strSQL.Append("Select *");
            strSQL.Append("FROM responsavelpc");
            strSQL.Append("Where NomeEquipamento like'" + NomeEquipamento +              "'");
        }
        MySqlDataAdapter oDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL.ToString(), oConn);
        oDA.Fill(oTable); hear appears the message that i put as title!
        dataGridView1.DataSource = oTable;
        oConn.Close();           
    }
```

this code is for a shearch my form have a dataGridView1 a comboBox1 and a button a textBox1 to use we have to chose what we have to shearch for exeample nomeequipamento and then we put in the textBox the Name of equipamento.Sry If the code is crap but iam a nobbie :)

Comment: That exception will also have some message with it Show that message. And also, at which point in your code are you getting this ?

Comment: Additionally, your code is horribly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. I *strongly* urge you to use parameterized SQL instead. (I *suspect* the problem here is that you're lacking a space after the second `like`, but that's just a guess at this point...)

Comment: your result SQL is `select *from responsavelpcwhere NomeEquipamento like`  - add some spaces

Comment: Also you don't need to call `.Open` and `.Close` methods if you are using DataAdapter.

Comment: This is for my last work for School (My School put me in a companie to stage  )my teacher says that i have to use Mysql and c#  .

Comment: Apears this to Additional information: The CommandText property has not been properly initialized.

Comment: Additional information: The CommandText property has not been properly initialized. Apeard this to HarveySpecter

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because of a missed white space. But its just my wild guess.

Here is a corrected code. I have added to comment to line

```
//codigo de pesquisa
        string strconexao = "persist security info =false ; server=localhost ; database= iconefileequipamentos; uid=root";
        MySqlConnection oConn =new MySqlConnection(strconexao);
        StringBuilder strSQL =new StringBuilder();
        DataTable oTable =new DataTable();
        MySqlCommand oCmd =new MySqlCommand();

        oConn.Open();

        if (comboBox1.Text =="NomeResponsavel")
        {
            string NomeResponsavel = textBox1.Text; 
            //Added white space at end of each line
            strSQL.Append("Select * ");
            strSQL.Append("FROM responsavelpc ");
            strSQL.Append("Where Nomeresponsavel like '" + NomeResponsavel + "'");
        }

        if (comboBox1.Text == "NomeEquipamento")
        {
            string NomeEquipamento = textBox1.Text;
            //Added white space at end of each line
            strSQL.Append("Select * ");
            strSQL.Append("FROM responsavelpc ");
            //Added white space after LIKE
            strSQL.Append("Where NomeEquipamento like '" + NomeEquipamento +"'"); 
        }
        MySqlDataAdapter oDA = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL.ToString(), oConn);
        oDA.Fill(oTable); hear appears the message that i put as title!
        dataGridView1.DataSource = oTable;
        oConn.Close();           
    }
```

PS: If you want to implement search feature you will have to use LIKE '% search_term %'. you are missing % sign in your code. Apart from that your code is not at all secure. Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Sameer but the error keep showing .Additional information: The CommandText property has not been properly initialized.  this appears too.